# The curve $(x+y+z)^3=27xyz$

Tags: algebraic-curves, rational-curves

Can someone point me to literature about the curve defined by $F(x,y,z):=(x+y+z)^3-27xyz$?  I'm sure this curve must be well-studied, due to the remarkable property that
$$
F(x^3,y^3,z^3) = \prod_{\alpha^3=\beta^3=1} (x+\alpha y+\beta z).
$$
But I'm not sure how to search for information about this.  Google tells me that this factorization is often assigned for homework in algebra classes, but I'm interested in the geometry of this curve.

Comment: What would you like to know about the geometry of this curve? How did you become interested in that particular curve?

Comment: I just want a pointer to the literature which can get me started on finding out what are the perspectives people have taken in understanding this curve.  It probably has a name, for instance.  I came across this curve in an old paper by Mordell, where it arose as (in some sense) the only interesting example of a certain phenomenon.  But Mordell's proof amounted to exhaustively ruling out all other cubic curves, and didn't give insight into why this one was so special.

Comment: This curve is of genus 0, isomorphic to $3X^2+Y^2-19X^2$?

Comment: A random sighting: Theorem 5b in "On the Foci of Circumparabolas" Forum Geometricorum
Volume 11 (2011) 57–63. No special name was given, just saying "the cubic C" given by...

Comment: I guess it parametrised by $(t^3:(1-t)^3:-1)$, and the equivalent form is thus $X^{1/3}+Y^{1/3}+Z^{1/3}=0$. See for instance http://books.google.com/books?id=LG0NHn7bPz0C&pg=PA209 for some discussion of the $(X+Y+Z)^3=27\rho XYZ$ family.

Comment: It is Example 1 on page 42 of the slides http://www.rimath.saitama-u.ac.jp/lab.jp/fsakai/saitama_09_03_bx.pdf‎

Comment: Thanks for the references, especially to du Val's book.  It looks like the pencil of cubic curves $(x+y+z)^3=mxyz$ is closely related to the Hesse pencil $x^3+y^3+z^3=cxyz$.  This definitely gets me started towards tracking down what's known, thanks!